# How do auto layout aspect/multiplier properties work?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, aspect-ratio

So I'm working on my first project and I'm having difficulty with scaling in auto layout.  In my storyboard (right; from the 3rd image on) and subsequent previews, font stays the same size and spacing from the container margins is decreased in smaller sized iPhones, which is what my current layout is producing.  However, I was hoping for results like the two images on the left (made in sketch), in which font is proportionally smaller and allowing a similar look between container margin and button on the 4" as opposed to the 4.7".  Is this possible to replicate or am I just crazy?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout (including auto layout) has to do with the size/position of view objects, e.g. a label. That's all. It has *nothing* to do with any other properties of those objects. Nothing whatever about layout is going to change the *font* of your label. If that's what you want, *you* must change the font (in code).

(To some extent, under certain circumstances, you can automate font size change relative to label size change by taking advantage of UILabel's `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property. But this is hardly to be relied on in general, and has nothing to do with auto layout per se.)

Comment: How do you believe I should reword the question to provide a more accurate representation of my thought?

Comment: @jonpeter It isn't a matter of rewording the question. It's a matter of fact. Automatic font size change is not going to happen. Accept that and move on.